# How to change the direction of the \makepsmarks choice of section title in header?

Tags: header-footer, memoir

I am having some trouble getting the command `\makepsmarks` behave as I want it to behave. I would like to have the section titles in the header behave as follows: No section titles should be displayed until the **second** page of a section. When one section stops in the middle of the page, I want the title in the header to be from that section, and not the section beginning on the page.

If you compile my minimal example and look on page 3, there should not be a section title in the header. On page 5 the section title should remain section one until the next page, because section one ends on that page.

I have tried to fiddle around with the `both`, `left` and `right` commands and changed the `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` commands around, but I haven't found a solution, so I hope you can help.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,onecolumn,oneside,final]{memoir}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[textwidth=10cm,textheight=22cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\makepagestyle{HDR}
\makepsmarks{HDR}{\nouppercaseheads 
\createmark{chapter}{left}{nonumber}{}{\space}
\createmark{section}{right}{nonumber}{}{\space} 
\makeheadrule{HDR}{10cm}{\normalrulethickness}
}
\makeoddhead{HDR}{\small\normalfont\mdseries\textsc{\leftmark}\hskip.3cm\vrule\hskip.3cm\bfseries\rightmark}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{HDR}{}{\thepage}{}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{HDR}
\chapter{Chapter One}
\lipsum
\section{Section One}
\lipsum
\section{Section Two}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: In the meantime, this question has been asked on [LaTeX Community](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=25286&view=unread#unread).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may make `\rightmark` use `\topmark` instead of `\firstmark`, but things will go wrong if a section starts at the top of a page. You can fix this (not guaranteed to work in any situation, though) by emitting a mark als before the section:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,onecolumn,oneside,final]{memoir}
\usepackage[textwidth=10cm,textheight=22cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}% just to avoid bad hyphenation

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype} % for better results
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makepagestyle{HDR}
\makepsmarks{HDR}{%
  \nouppercaseheads
  \createmark{chapter}{left}{nonumber}{}{\space}%
  \createmark{section}{right}{nonumber}{}{\space}%
  \makeheadrule{HDR}{10cm}{\normalrulethickness}%
}
\makeoddhead{HDR}{%
  \small\normalfont\mdseries
  \textsc{\leftmark}%
  \hspace{.3cm}\vrule\hspace{.3cm}%
  \textbf{\rightmark}%
}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{HDR}{}{\thepage}{}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\rightmark}{\expandafter\@rightmark\topmark\@empty\@empty}
\makeatother

\let\memoirsection\section
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{oom}{%
  \markright{#3}% emit a mark also before the section
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {\memoirsection{#3}}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
      {\memoirsection[#1]{#3}}
      {\memoirsection[#1][#2]{#3}}%
    }%
}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{HDR}
\chapter{Chapter One}
\lipsum
\section{Section One}
\lipsum
\section{Section Two}
\lipsum
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{Section Three}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]